# highlight the keywords in autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i want to highlight the keywords according to its autocomplete search, like if i type a then the results it gives:
 java
 javascript
so in this j**a**v**a**
           j**a**v**a**script
and then if i type av  then j**ava**
           j**ava**script should get highlight or bold according to the search.

Below is my code:

**javascipt**

```
     $(this).ready( function() {  
        $("#id").autocomplete({  
            minLength: 1,  
            source:   
            function(req, add){  
            //alert("xdhf");
            $.ajax({
                             url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/trainer_dashboard/autocomplete_batchsearch",
                            data: req,
                            dataType: 'json', 
                            type: "post",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data){
                                    //alert(data);
                                      if(data.response =="true"){  
                                        add(data.message);  
                                        console.log(data);

                                         }                                      
                                },
                          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                            {
                                alert(thrownError);
                            }
            });
             },  
         });  
    });
```

**controller**

```
public function autocomplete_batchsearch()
{
    //$user_id=get_cookie('trainer_login_user_id');
    $keyword = $this->input->post('term'); 

     $data['response'] = 'false'; //Set default response  
    $query = $this->trainer_dashboard_model ->batchsearch($keyword); //Search DB 
    //echo"";print_r($query); 
    if( ! empty($query) )  
    {  
        $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response  
        $data['message'] = array(); //Create array  
        foreach( $query as $row )  
        {  
            $data['message'][] = array(   
                                    'id'=>$row->id,  
                                    'value' => $row->id,  
                                    ''  
                                 );  //Add a row to array  
        }  
    }  
    if('IS_AJAX')  
    {  
        echo json_encode($data); //echo json string if ajax request  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $this->load->view('trainer_dashboard_view',$data); //Load html view of search results  
    } 

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this may help https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html?highlight=highlight#highlight_phrase

Comment: no this will highlight all the output which are fetched from database.